# System-Agnostic's tag wiki needs improvement

Tags: discussion, tags

RPG SE uses [system-agnostic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-agnostic) a lot, and in a rather esoteric fashion.

[Its tag wiki](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/system-agnostic/info), however, is a sad, sad thing:

> ## About [system-agnostic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-agnostic)
>
> Not related to any one particular system of rules.

This really needs more information. Users should be able to look at the tag wiki to find out which kinds of questions need the [system-agnostic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-agnostic) tag (vs. a specific system tag or no system tags at all), as well as obtain answers about how to structure their answers in a "system-agnostic" way. [See Tag Wiki Best Practices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69584/248443).

(Why don't I just do it? Well, I've got some "I know it when I see it" intuition about the tag, but I really can't figure out how to express the answers to these questions in clear words that other people can understand.)

Comment: One thing that bears clarifying is the difference between multi-system (compare [tag:dnd-4e] to [tag:gurps-4e]) and broad system (the root [tag:dungeons-and-dragons], or [tag:fate]) tag usage vs [tag:system-agnostic].

Comment: If we can get that wiki to somehow say "don't use this just because your situation occurs in other systems," I would be kinda happy. That is probably low priority to include though.

Comment: A (non-exhaustive) listing of System-Agnostic's principle uses: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/3054/77

Comment: I have updated the tag wiki.  Comments welcome.

Comment: @mxyzplk That is definitely a good start.

Comment: I think most users see only the excerpt of the tag, right? In that case, I suggest using @mxyzplk 's "[The solution to the question is] not directly tied to a game's mechanics, or [...] you [...] don't care what."

Comment: You see the except on hover-over, you see the full wiki when you click through.

Comment: Edited excerpt.